# Responsive Image in both height and width

Tags: css

The following link is responsive regarding its width, but we need it to be responsive in height also so that the user doesn't have to scroll the image on any size screen. I tried max-height:100% and max-width:100% but no luck. How is this accomplished?  Thanks!

http://www.photoeye.com/gallery/nick-brandt-2013/enlargement.cfm?ip=1&i=24&id=185363&pid=Portfolio14#22

Comment: If you don't want distortion then I think its better to be responsive in only width or height. And then set center with overflow hidden.

Comment: Might it be that you have to set max-height: 100% for the containing elements also?

Answer (score 0):

You can only fix it in height if you know the ratio of the img.

Then you can make use of the [viewport height length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh)

```
img {
  max-width: $imgRatio * 80vh; /* max 80 % of viewport height for img */
}
```

Browsers are not able to limit height in both axis while keeping ratio.

To fix it in both directions you'd need another container, which gets the max-width based on viewport height.

Beware that [vh doesn't work in all browsers yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), and that mobile browsers change vh when the toolbar is out of view, or the keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Height limitation is a constant problem. Can't be solved (from my experience) by CSS alone. Thus portrait (non-landscape) images are often a problem in image galleries. My approach:

**1) old-school width-only to start with:**

```
.fullsize img { max-width: 200px; }
```

**2) at least “limit the damage” in response to screen heights**

```
@media screen and (min-height:400px) { .fullsize img { max-width: 400px; } }
@media screen and (min-height:800px) { .fullsize img { max-width: 800px; } }
```

**3) Prepare two more classes, to be applied by javascript** (after format measuring)

```
.fullsize.fullwidth img {
    width: 100%      !important;
    height: auto     !important;
    max-width: none  !important; /* yes, back to none */
    max-height: none !important;
}

.fullsize.fullheight img {
    width: auto      !important;
    height: 100%     !important;
    max-width: none  !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
/* (!important needed for precedence over media queries) */
```

Lastly, the javascript:

```
App.adjustFullsize = function( t ) {
    t.each( function(){
        var p=$(this).parent('.fullsize:first');

        var dispW= $(window).width(),
            dispH= $(window).height() - 126, /* fugde-factor deducts header, footers, etc. */
            dispRatio = (dispH>0) ? (dispW/dispH) : 1.0,

            // no need to get real width, as long as
            // ratio is correct $('<img/>').attr()
            imgW = $(this).width(),
            imgH = $(this).height(),
            imgRatio = (imgH>0) ? (imgW/imgH) : 1.0;


        if ( imgRatio > dispRatio ) // hits left-right of bbox
            p.removeClass('fullheight').addClass('fullwidth').css('height','');
        else  // hits top-bottom of bbox
            p.removeClass('fullwidth').addClass('fullheight').css('height',dispH);
    });
};
```

**4) You should fire the resize event generously.** Basically, because it needs to be fired after *images* (not just the DOM) have loaded, however not every device reliably fires the .load()-event, in particular if cached.

```
/* depend on image load, NOT jQuery.ready(). Warning, not every device fires load() events, i.e. ipad */
$('.fullsize img').load( function() {
    App.adjustFullsize( $(this) );
});

/* trigger again on resizes (includes tablet turnaround etc) */
$(this).resize( function() {
    App.adjustFullsize( $('.fullsize img') );
});

$( function() {
    App.adjustFullsize( $('.fullsize img') );
});
```

Thus: Consider another call via jQuery.delay() with 100ms delay. (Won't flash/jump, if everything is fine already, and will help, if not.)